# How can I search for all points with a specific range (radius) of another point?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

The syntax I use to query for polygons in range of other Points

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.myTable
INNER JOIN
    dbo.myPOI ON myTable.geog.STIntersects(myPOI.geog) = 1
```

But, to query points of interests, I use a radius and I'm using this.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.myTable
INNER JOIN
    dbo.myPOI2 ON myTable.geog.STDistance(myPOI2.geog) <= POI2.Point_Radius
```

Is there a better way to write this? Can the queries be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the queries themselves be improved?
>
> ```
> ...
> dbo.myPOI2 ON myTable.geog.STDistance(myPOI2.geog) <= POI2.Point_Radius
> ```

Yes. That's going to be slow. You could massively improve that query by buffering the point and finding the `intersects`:

```
ON myTable.geog.STIntersects(myPOI.geog.STBuffer(PP.Point_Radius)) = 1
```

You can make this even better in your case because the radius is provided on the row, rather than in the query. You can store the geometery returned by `STBuffer` on the table instead of the point. If you ever want to to find the center point (which you'll probably never need), you can use the GIS function [STCentroid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stcentroid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017).

### Other implementations

As a side note, this type of query is done with [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) in PostGIS and will run on the index.

Comment: Thanks Evan, Why have you changed the datatype of my columns from Geography to Geometry after you edited my question?

Comment: @Mazhar oversight, there it's fixed.